# Measure theory and almost surely

Tags: integration, measure-theory, expected-value

Is it correct to say that if $E[z] < \infty$ then $z$ is almost surely finite?

Comment: Indeed, if $p(z=\infty)>0$, then automatically $E[z]=\infty$ (and if both $z=+\infty$ and $z=-\infty$ had positive probability, $E[z]$ would not be defined)

Comment: In particular, if $Ez$ is defined then $z$ is measurable and we have $E|z| < \infty$ and hence $|z|$ is finite ae.

Answer (score 0):

In probability theory we consider only real valued measurable functions. If you are asking if $\int f \, d\mu <\infty$ implies $f$ is almost everywhere finite (in a general measure space setting) then the answer is no: take $f \equiv -\infty$. (You must always distinguish between $\int f \, d\mu <\infty$ and $\int f \, d\mu  \in \mathbb R$)

Comment: Sure, in the back of my mind I implicitly thought about $\int f d\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, but I get your point.